# Integer algorithm: find a mathematical function that fulfills given conditions

Tags: algorithm, math, integer

Given an integer x in the interval [1 .. 6], I am looking for two mathematical functions `y1` and `y2` so that:

1. y1(x) ∈ [1 .. 6], y2(x) ∈ [1 .. 6]
2. y1(x) ≠ y2(x) ≠ x
3. y1(x) and y2(x) are integers

I tried `y1(x) = 7-x` and `y2(x) = (1+x)%6` where `%` is the remainder or modulo operation.

That solution does not work for `x=6`. I get `y1(x) = y2(x) = 1`, which does not fulfills the condition 2. Neither for `x=3` and `x=5`.

Does anyone sees a working solution?

Comment: You need to be more precise with your question. Do you need two functions that return values between [1..6] for *all* values of x?

Comment: What does condition number 2 mean? Do you mean no value of `y` can equal any value of `x`? Or do you mean `y1(x) <> x` and `y2(x) <> x` and `y1(x) <> y2(x)`?

Comment: Unless you can edit the question to be more clearly about programming, I think this would fit better at http://math.stackexchange.com or something...

Comment: `y1=(x+1)%6+1` and `y2=(x+2)%6+1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
y1=(x % 6) +1

y2=((x+1) % 6) +1
```

Functions as table:

```
x  y1  y2
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
4   5   6
5   6   1
6   1   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, y1=1+((x+1) %6) and y2=(1+(x+2) %6) both satisfy your request.

I guess though you were thinking about something with a unified distribution of some sort (which is usually the motivation for such attempts...).